# ActiveAndroid ORM annotation

Tags: android, orm, mapping, relational-database, activeandroid

I want to map convert to this class and write to database using "**ActiveAndroid**". I don't know what kind of annotiations should I put?. **organizationId** should be unique. Should I write some methods for select query?.

```
public class Organization extends Model {

    private String organizationId;

    private List<Doctor> doctors;

    private String organizationName;

    private String photoUrl;

    private Address address;

    private Set<String> phoneNumber;

    private String faxNumber;

    private String key;

    private int numberOfDoctors;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the ActiveAndroid documentation?  I think that tells you what annotations to use.

Answer (score 0):

for simple column use @Column annotation such as:

```
@Column(name="org_name")
private String organizationName;
```

and for unique constraint use

```
 @Column(name="org_id" , unique = true , onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.IGNORE)
private String organizationId;
```

and do not forget putting table annotation for class

```
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization extends Model {
```